# Parameterized variable names as task input in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I've been trying to make a YAML template that first uses the AzureKeyVault@1 task to get the value ofsome Azure KeyVault secrets, and then uses these secrets for the sqlUsername and sqlPassword in asqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1 task.

I want to make the names of the KeyVault secrets a parameter, so that this template can be used for many different situations.

I've successfully used this technique before, with an AzureKeyVault@1 task and then an AzurePowerShell@4 task, where the secret gets injected as an environment variable for the PowerShell script.

This is a dressed down version of the working template:

```
parameters:
- name: subscription
  type: string
- name: keyVaultSecretName
  type: string
- name: keyVault
  type: string
jobs:
- job: Run_PowerShell_With_Secret
  pool:
    name: Azure Pipelines
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
  - task: AzureKeyVault@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
      keyVaultName:  ${{ parameters.keyVault }}
      secretsFilter: ${{ parameters.keyVaultSecretName }}
  - task: AzurePowerShell@4
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
      ScriptPath: 'some_script.ps1'
      azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
    env: 
      SECRETVALUE: $(${{ parameters.keyVaultSecretName }})
```

And here is the template where I can't get the same technique to work:

```
parameters:
- name: subscription
  type: string
- name: keyVault
  type: string
- name: sqlServerName
  type: string
- name: sqlDatabaseName
  type: string
- name: sqlServerAdminSecretName
  type: string
- name: sqlServerPasswordSecretName
  type: string
- name: dacpacName
  type: string
- name: artifactName
  type: string
jobs:
- job: Deploy_SQL_Database
  pool:
    name: Azure Pipelines
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      artifact: ${{ parameters.artifactName }}_artifacts
  - task: AzureKeyVault@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
      keyVaultName:  ${{ parameters.keyVault }}
      secretsFilter: '${{ parameters.sqlServerAdminSecretName }}, ${{ parameters.sqlServerPasswordSecretName }}'
  - task: sqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscription }}
      ServerName: ${{ parameters.sqlServerName }}.database.windows.net
      DatabaseName: ${{ parameters.sqlDatabaseName }}
      sqlUsername: $(${{ parameters.sqlServerAdminSecretName }})
      sqlPassword: $(${{ parameters.sqlServerPasswordSecretName }})
      DacpacFile:  $(Pipeline.Workspace)\${{ parameters.dacpacName }}.dacpac
```

I can get the template to work if I hardcode the secret names:

```
parameters:
- name: subscriptionName
  type: string
- name: keyVault
  type: string
- name: sqlServerName
  type: string
- name: sqlDatabaseName
  type: string
- name: dacpacName
  type: string
- name: artifactName
  type: string
jobs:
- job: Deploy_${{ parameters.sqlDatabaseName }}_Database
  pool:
    name: Azure Pipelines
    vmImage: windows-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: none
  - task: AzureKeyVault@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscriptionName }}
      keyVaultName:  ${{ parameters.keyVault }}
      secretsFilter: 'SQLServerAdmin, SQLServerPassword'
  - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
    inputs:
      artifact: ${{ parameters.artifactName }}_artifacts
  - task: sqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.subscriptionName }}
      ServerName: ${{ parameters.sqlServerName }}.database.windows.net
      DatabaseName: ${{ parameters.sqlDatabaseName }}
      sqlUsername: $(sqlServerAdmin)
      sqlPassword: $(sqlServerPassword)
      DacpacFile:  $(Pipeline.Workspace)\${{ parameters.dacpacName }}.dacpac
```

Although this works for us for now, I find this sub-optimal. Is there any way I can make these parameterized variable names work?

Comment: Seems it's not work in `sqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1` task, could you please try to output the parameterized variable names in `AzurePowerShell@4` task and check if that works?

Comment: Hi Andy, I already did. In an AzurePowerShell@4 task I'm able to pass my secret as an environment variable to the script. I'm not outputting the variable there, but I am succesfully using it. (`env: SECRETVALUE: $(${{ parameters.keyVaultSecretName }})`)

Comment: So, just as I mentioned it appears only works in the specific tasks, at least not work in `sqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1` task. Based on my test cannot find a better way to work around it. Since it works in PowerShell task, so you can try running scripts to deploy if possible.